# Sort by a field and check for equality by another field in C#

Tags: c#, collections, sortedset

I have a class like this

```
public enum RespondantRole
{
    Operator = 0,
    Supervisor = 1, 
    Director = 2
}

public class Respondant: IComparable<Respondant>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RespondantRole Role { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Respondant other)
    {
        return ((int)this.Role).CompareTo((int)other.Role);
    }
}
```

I wish to create a `SortedSet` with this class. But I want the ordering to be by Role i.e. Operators, Supervisors and Director. However, since this doesn't allow duplicate I want the check for equality to be based on the `Name` field which is unique.

So, when I initialize this set using the below code I get the correct order but only 3 elements since the other three get duplicate issues on subsequent adds.

How do I have this set sorted by role while unique constraint is based on the Name attribute.

```
public class CallCenterManager
{
    private SortedSet<Respondant> AvailableRespondants;
    public CallCenterManager()
    {
        AvailableRespondants = new ObservableSortedSet<Respondant>();
        for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            AvailableRespondants.Add(new Respondant() { Name = $"Operator{i}", Role = RespondantRole.Operator });
            if(i < 5)
            {
                AvailableRespondants.Add(new Respondant() { Name = $"Supervisor{i}", Role = RespondantRole.Supervisor });
            }
            if(i < 3)
            {
                AvailableRespondants.Add(new Respondant() { Name = $"Director{i}", Role = RespondantRole.Director });
            }
        }
    }
```

when I run the above code I get 3 entries in the set

```
{ Name = "Operator0", Role = Operator} 
{ Name = "Supervisor0", Role = Supervisor}
{ Name = "Director0", Role = Director}
```

Now this is sorted as per the Role level but since the `compareTo` is based on the Role the next set of `Respondant` with the same role does not get inserted. 
i.e. You do not see `{ Name = "Operator1", Role = Operator}`

So how I would like tthe output to be is

```
{ Name = "Operator0", Role = Operator} 
{ Name = "Operator1", Role = Operator} 
{ Name = "Operator2", Role = Operator} 
.. upto 10 entries
{ Name = "Supervisor0", Role = Supervisor}
{ Name = "Supervisor1", Role = Supervisor}
.. up to 5 entries
{ Name = "Director0", Role = Director}
.. upto 3 entries
```

Comment: If I understand you well, you want two levels of sorting, first by role, then by name?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "while unique constraint is based on the Name attribute". What "Name attribute" are you referring to? I don't see any attributes set in the code. Do you mean the `Name` property? And if so, since they all have unique names, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Do you mean you want the comparison to first compare by `Role`, and then by `Name`?

Comment: Do you want to group by role, then sort by Name? Please provide example Input and Output so we can understand your goal.

Comment: updated please check

Comment: @thebenman: Please make a example with enough input data that we can actually get the pattern. Give us at least 6-10 example entries and how you want them sorted.

Comment: So you want several passes, with the later ones having a "Minimum Role" to evne be on the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your CompareTo in this way

```
public int CompareTo(Respondant other)
{
    int x = ((int)this.Role).CompareTo((int)other.Role);
    if(x == 0)
        return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    else
        return x;
}
```

When you add an element to the SortedSet class it is immediately compared against the other elements already inside the class to find the exact spot in the internal list to keep everything sorted. But, when you compare using only the role, after the first three elements, you start to return 0 from your CompareTo method.
SortedSet doesn't allow duplicates and if you return 0 it takes this result as sign of equality between two elements and doesn't add the new element to its internal list.

By the way, I think you are using the SortedSet class. I cannot find an ObservableSortedSet in the class libraries.

Comment: Thank you this works. `ObservableSortedSet` is an extension I am working on. I forgot to swap it with SortedSet for showing here.